# Mysql error echoing the variable

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, echo

I have a mysql query as below -

```
    $id_order_last="15";
    $id_order[]=array();
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM `ps_orders` WHERE `id_order`> 
    $id_order_last  order by `id_order`";
    echo $sql1;
    $result1= mysql_query($sql1);
    $cnt=1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        /*$id_order[$i]=$row['$id_order'];*/
        echo $row['$id_order']."<br />";
        $cnt++;
        echo $cnt."<br />";
}
```

As you can see i have the `$id_order_last` set 15 so it displaying the value as 15 when echoed. To check sql i echoed it and it display

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_orders` WHERE `id_order`> 15 order by `id_order`
```

So i get in the sql, run in phpmyadmin and the tuples which get returns was correct value. It show the good result means 17 and 18 which were in database. Which means the query is correct!

then it echoed 2 and 3 the cnt++ value  while `$row['$id_order']` is still empty only `<br />` is shown up as space.

THough i also tried the for loop to print the whole things but it still not showing up?

```
$i=1;
for($i;$i<=$cnt;$i++)
{
    echo $id_order_last."<br />";
    echo $id_order[$i]."<br />";
    $id_order_last=$id_order[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use echo $row['id_order'] in place of echo $row['$id_order']

remove $.
```

Comment: though both gave same ans but i wan give this to some one new thanks u both of your for this help

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$row['$id_order']` to `$row['id_order']`

```
$id_order_last="15";
$sql1="SELECT * FROM `ps_orders` WHERE `id_order`> 
$id_order_last  order by `id_order`";
echo $sql1;
$result1= mysql_query($sql1);
$cnt=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $id_order[]=$row['id_order'];
    echo $row['id_order']."<br />";
    $cnt++;
    echo $cnt."<br />";
}

echo "<pre />";
print_r($id_order);
```